# how to get value of inner html objects of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have 3 span elements inside a div. the whole div will be created dynamically inside a loop. 
here is the code

```
 $.each(data.Payload, function(index, value){
      stmt+='<li class="list-group-item">'+
                 '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">'+
                    '<div class="refugeeInfo">'+
                       '<span class="name" style="cursor: pointer">'+ value.firstName +' '+value.lastName+'</span><br/>'+
                       '<label><strong>unID: </strong><span class="unid" style="cursor: pointer;"> '+ value.unID +'</span></label>'+
                      '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp'+
                      '<label><strong>rmsID: </strong><span class="rmsid" style="cursor: pointer">'+ value.rmsID +'</span></label><br/>'+
                      '</div>'+
                 '</li>'
        });
```

now when i click on (".refugeeInfo") div i need to show the value of name, unID and rmsID. wjat I tried

```
$('.refugeeInfo').click(function(){
            var name=$(this).children('.name').text();
            var unID=$(this).children('.unid').text();
            var rmsID=$(this).children('.rmsid').text();
            console.log("name: "+name);
            console.log("unID: "+unID);
            console.log("rmsID: "+rmsID);
})
```

but the result showing only name. unID and rmsID is vacant.

Comment: Where is `refugeeProfile`??

Comment: sorry john that was refugeeInfo. I changed that

Comment: `.unid` and `.rmsid` are not direct children of `.refugeeInfo`. use `find()` instead of `children()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find()` instead of `children()` Problem is your `.unid` and `.rmsid` are nested inside a `label` tag.. the selector `children()` works only for direct descendants of the parent. Here these 2 elements are not direct descendants.

**[From the document](https://api.jquery.com/children/)**.

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

```
$('.refugeeInfo').click(function(){
   var name = $(this).children('.name').text();
   var unID = $(this).find('.unid').text();
   var rmsID = $(this).find('.rmsid').text();

   console.log("name: " + name);
   console.log("unID: " + unID);
   console.log("rmsID: " + rmsID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `find()`

```
$('.refugeeInfo').click(function(){
            var name=$(this).children('.name').text();
            var unID=$(this).find('.unid').text();
            var rmsID=$(this).find('.rmsid').text();
            console.log("name: "+name);
            console.log("unID: "+unID);
            console.log("rmsID: "+rmsID);
})
```

Comment: .val() will not work in span. but .text() does. But thank u for .find()

Comment: Thank you for reminding, my mistake. I say `.unid` class as that of label, so told to use `val()` instead of `text()`.